# How to execute nodejs request module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Nodejs request library built on top of http,https. So i try to execute nodejs server from request object, its says not part of request.

So how to execute or call  below code in express ?

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 //Load the request module
 var request = require('request');

 //Lets configure and request
 app.request({
     url: 'https://modulus.io/contact/demo', //URL to hit
     qs: {from: 'blog example', time: +new Date()}, //Query string data
     method: 'POST',
     //Lets post the following key/values as form
     json: {
         field1: 'data',
         field2: 'data'
     }
 }, function(error, response, body){
     if(error) {
         console.log(error);
     } else {
         console.log(response.statusCode, body);
     }
 });
 app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to acomplish

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. The point of Express is to run an HTTP server. While it is possible to make an HTTP request from Node while running Express, you would normally only do so in a function which handles a route. i.e. A browser makes a request to Express, then Express makes a request to some other server, gets a response from it, then uses the data in that response to determine how to respond to the first request. Your code is trying to send a request on startup instead of in resource to a route being hit. You don't even have any routes.

Comment: Additionally, while Express has request objects, they describe incoming requests. If you want to create an outgoing request, you'd need to `require` a suitable module.

Comment: *Nodejs request library built on top of http,https.* — That doesn't mean it subclasses the `http` module.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, what do you expect from your code?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're using `app.request` while you should just be using `request`, which is the variable that points to the module itself. So your code should be:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//Load the request module
var request = require('request');

//Lets configure and request
request({
        url: 'https://modulus.io/contact/demo', //URL to hit
        qs: {from: 'blog example', time: +new Date()}, //Query string data
        method: 'POST',
        //Lets post the following key/values as form
        json: {
            field1: 'data',
            field2: 'data'
        }
    }, function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(response.statusCode, body);
        }
    });
app.listen(8080);
```